# Dealing with unknown UTF8 characters

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm grabbing data from a website. The problem is some of the characters returned are question marks. How do I show their actual characters instead of the question marks?

Here is my code:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    do {
        let html = String(decoding: data!, as: UTF8.self)

        print(html)
    } catch {
        //
    }
}.resume()
```

It won't let me use anything like `UTF32.self`.

I tried using this code instead:

```
let html = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
```

Which returns completely `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

Ended up using `.ascii` which worked:

```
String(data: data!, encoding: .ascii)
```

Comment: I'm betting it's actually Latin-1 (`.isoLatin1`), and that `.ascii` is just falling back to Latin-1 for unknown characters. There is no ASCII character that would not decode correctly in UTF-8. ASCII is a 7-bit subset of both UTF-8 and Latin-1 (and most other 8-bit encodings).

Answer (score 1):

When you say "their actual characters," what characters do you believe those are (and why do you believe those are the characters)? By "question marks" I assume you mean �, which is REPLACEMENT CHARACTER. That's the character that is shown when the character is not a valid encoding. The reason `String(data:encoding:)` is returning nil is because that's what it does if the encoding is invalid. `String(decoding:as:)` replaces invalid characters with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER and otherwise does the best it can.

So the underlying problem is that the data you're decoding is not UTF-8. If it's "almost UTF-8" then something like UTF-32 would never work. They have no overlap of valid encodings (except NUL). More likely, the data is encoded with some form of extended ASCII like Windows-1251, which encodes Latin and Cyrillic, and is compatible with UTF-8 in Latin, but not in Cyrillic.

You need to determine what the encoding of the page is, and use that encoding with `String(data:encoding:)`. Many encodings are ambiguous, and the extended ASCII encodings are especially ambiguous, so there is no way to automatically determine it. Often it will be returned as part of the headers, but it depends on what webpage you're fetching.

Comment: The web page I am decoding has `<meta charset="UTF-8">`, so why would it contain replacement characters? What decoding would you recommend for this case? Thanks Rob!

Comment: Nevermind I'm dumb it looks like `.ascii` works perfectly

Comment: The webpage is incorrect in that case, and if you control it, you should fix it. If it's actually encoded in Latin-1 (which I suspect), then it should be `<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">`. (Latin-1 is one of the "extended ASCII" systems I mentioned. There are a lot of them.)